# How should arrays be stored in PostgreSQL when used as a datastore with GeoServer 2.14+?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, wfs

I am storing a string array in PostgreSQL to serve through WFS in GeoServer 2.14.1.  As a test, I have two columns in my table; one column is a character varying array and this other is a text array data type.  When I register the layer in GeoServer only the character varying array shows up in the feature type details.  When I try to access the data via WFS, the value in the property shows up as the memory representation of the object, e.g. "[Ljava.lang.String;@1748e3a9" and is not serializing the object.  Does anyone know the proper way to either store string arrays in PostgreSQL to use with GeoServer or properly configure GeoServer to serialize array data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per responses on the GeoServer-Users list, the array support is for low-level reading and writing of array data in PostgreSQL, but currently there is no support for encoding array data to WFS output formats.

There is no indication if encoding output array data in WFS is on the roadmap, but was directed to the following link if anyone is interested in the feature or has the bandwidth to contribute the enhancement.

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer